# How can I make the hat symbol in Anki?

Tags: accents, anki

In regular LaTeX I can simply use:

```
\^{\omega}
```

to get Omega hat. However, Anki returns `\^ω` where `\^` is marked red. I am unsure where to look this up.

Comment: Are you sure that you use LaTeX and not rather MathJax (which uses a TeX-flavored syntax, but is not exactly TeX)? If I test the above code in an [online MathJax viewer](https://saxarona.github.io/mathjax-viewer/), I get exactly what you describe. In fact, `\^` is not meant to be used in math mode in TeX, which is probably why it is not implemented in MathJax. Use `\hat{\omega}` instead.

Comment: `\hat` does the trick in Anki. I used Overleaf with TexLive's pdftex to check if I remembered it wrong.

Comment: overleaf would have shown an error for `\^`:  `LaTeX Warning: Command \^ invalid in math mode on input line 4.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.4 $\^{\omega}
               $
? `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not provide a full example but

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$\^{\omega}$
\end{document}
```

produces an error in latex, your error is unrelated to anki:

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \^ invalid in math mode on input line 4.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.4 $\^{\omega}
               $
? 
! Improper \spacefactor.
<recently read> \spacefactor 
                             
l.4 $\^{\omega}
               $
?
```

Use `\hat`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$\hat{\omega}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right. `\^` can only be used outside the math environment to create the intended accent. Thank you.